# install ubuntu with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I finally decided to clear my hard disk and start over again. I need to install both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. I currently have two problems:

1. I have installed Ubuntu on the fresh 320 GB drive, but when I restart I can't boot into my Ubuntu, except when I insert the flash drive I used for the installation of my system during the boot process.
2. What's the best and easiest way to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a seperate partition, and how do I go about the partitioning?

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, the best way to install Ubuntu in a different partition is as follows:

- Partition your Hard Drive into two paritions and install Windows 7 to your first partition and leave the second partition unformatted.
- Now, install Ubuntu 12.04 by pointing the rest of your unpartitioned area of hard disk as the installation location.
- The partitioning size you can do according to the usage of each of the OS you have. (The one OS you use primarly can be given more space). But, it is better to give at least 10 GB for one OS since you have 320 GB in total with you.

**Note:** If you try to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu installation, then, Windows 7 will erase the grub (The Windows domination :)) and that you may need to install seperately later (using the command "sudo grub-install" by booting with the booting device you used for Ubuntu installation), which can become difficult for you if you are new with this.

Answer (score 0):

If your system will boot with the USB key inserted but not when its not then that implies that you installed GRUB to the USB key rather than the HDD

Boot back into the system and open a terminal and then issue the following commnads

This presumes you have one HDD @ SDA

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

you may need to run update-grub too but I refer you to these pages

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: tnx, i'll try that, what about my second question "2. What's the best and easiest way to install ubuntu 12.04 on a seperate partition, and how do i go about the partitioning "